vba AutoFilter Cells with blank background color but have data
how to AutoFilter Cells with blank background color but have data?
What value do I need to pass in colorIndex to get the following results ?
enter image description here
Sub FilterByColor()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim colorIndex As Long
    Set rng = Range("A1:A100")
    colorIndex = -4142
    'What is the value of null color?
    
    rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=colorIndex, Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
End Sub

call  FilterBycolor()
when  colorIndex = -4142 :
enter image description here
This is not the output I want.
I have tried colorIndex =-4142 ,xlNone , xlColorIndexAutomatic , xlColorIndexNone , None , Null , vbWhite.
None of them met my expectations. please help me.thanks!

You don't need to use the Criteria1 argument.
Pls try
Rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:=xlFilterNoFill

Microsoft documentation:

Range.AutoFilter method (Excel)


As mentioned you are filtering on a non filled cell so just the following will create the filter as you have shown in the image
Sub FilterByColor()
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Set rng = Range("A1:A100")
    
    rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:=xlFilterNoFill
End Sub




XlAutoFilterOperator enumeration (Excel):
xlAnd
xlBottom10Items
xlBottom10Percent
xlFilterCellColor
xlFilterDynamic
xlFilterFontColor
xlFilterIcon
xlFilterValues
xlOr
xlTop10Items
xlTop10Percent
it doesn't have xlFilterNoFill

The enumeration value for xlFilterNoFill is 12 and has been around for quite some time. Are you saying that it doesn't work?

xlFilterNoFill is 12 ,it doesn't work. Do I need to install some sth?
erro number is 5. What is the difference between. Net and VBA?

Shouldn't need to install anything else. I have run it on Excel 2013 and 2021. The  xlFilterNoFill  is from Excel 2007. What do you get if you record a macro while manually setting the filter as desired?

Recording macros:
Range("A1:D4").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(4, 0, 2), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
if i run this macros,It doesn't work as well as I need..

Interesting, not what I and others get it seems. What version of Excel are your using. Maybe its too old for the function. As indicated the docs state Excel 2007 and up

wps office 12.1.0.19302
It's a pity that the problem is caused by the software version. I am communicating with relevant personnel in wps forum. There should be no solution at present.
